# Problema com Dot-Star no Regex

Tags: php, regex

Estou tentando criar um interpretador (parser) de `robots.txt` com Regex porém não consigo fazer que a expressão fique certa. Fiz vários testes no Regex101 e mesmo assim não atingi um resultado esperado.

Minha expressão regular:

```
/user-agent: (bot|\*)\n*((disallow:\s*(?<disallow>.*)|allow:\s*(?<allow>.*)|sitemap:\s*(?<sitemap>.*))\n*)+/gi
```

Minha váriavel de testes:

```
User-agent: *

Disallow: /exemplo/
Allow: /dolor/
Disallow: /sit/
Allow: /amet/

Sitemap: http://www.loremipsum.com/sitemap.xml
```

Na imagem vocês podem ver o resultado que o Regex101 retorna e aquele que eu queria que retornasse.

[image: Como o código é reproduzido e como ele deverá ficar]

Comment: Você pode explicar o que exatamente quer fazer com o regex? É mais fácil que identificar as cores do seu exemplo.

Comment: Quero colocar os valores de `disallow`,`allow` e `sitemap` dentro de um array homônimo. Por exemplo, `/amet/` estaria dentro do array `allow`.

Comment: Talvez seja melhor você repensar como vai usar esse regex. Acho que não é possível um grupo com vários resultados, ou vários grupos com mesmo nome. Uma alternativa mais fácil é fazer por etapas. Por exemplo, pode pegar apenas os `Disallow` usando `(?<=disallow:)\s?(.*)` e fazer o mesmo para os `Allow` e outros elementos do robots.

Comment: @Molx Só que aí tem um problema: a expressão regular vai pegar todos os `allow` e `disallow` do arquivo. Eu queria que só pegasse aquelas regras que estivessem dentro do `user-agent` certo (como `*` ou `bot`).

Comment: Pode ser em Perl?

Comment: Não precisa. Já consegui. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de alguns dias pensando a respeito de como fazer um *parser*, consegui criar algo parecido com *Regex*.

Só que o código não é 100% perfeito e por isso ainda estou o testando.